# I am trying to create buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, window

I am trying to create buttons in a program to take the user to other screens. I have created the images on labels but not sure on how to make them into functioning buttons that take users to another page. You can see in my code the 2 buttons i need are the search quote and new quote. Thank you

```
from tkinter import *  
class Window(): 
def __init__(self,master): #constructor   
self.master = master       
self.master.title("Borras Roofing Quotation System") #sets title of window

self.master.geometry("2160x1440") #sets size of window  
self.master.configure(background = "white") # sets background colour of window.

self.Borras = PhotoImage(file = "Borras.Logo.PNG") #sets up image
self.BorrasLabel  = Label(self.master, image = self.Borras, bg = "white", width='1000', height= '500') #puts image onto label  
self.BorrasLabel.pack()  

self.newquote = PhotoImage(file = "Process_New_Quote_Button.PNG") #sets up image  
self.newquoteLabel = Label(self.master, image = self.newquote, bg = "white") #puts image onto label  
self.newquoteLabel.place(x = 200, y = 500) 

self.searchquote = PhotoImage(file = "Search_Current_Quote_Button.PNG") #sets up image  
self.searchquoteLabel = Label(self.master, image = self.searchquote, bg = "white") #puts image onto label  
self.searchquoteLabel.place(x = 800, y = 500)

root = Tk() 
userPassWindow = Window(root)  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want to know how to give functionality to your buttons? Have you tried adding `command`? `For example, b = Button(text="Click Me", command=function_name)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inheritance and make each window child of the `Toplevel` widget.

***Example:***

```
from Tkinter import *

class search(Toplevel):
      # Just inherits TopLevel window
     def __init__(self, parent, master=None):
           Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
           #Save  parent reference to modify parent view from search view
           self.parent = parent

class quote(Toplevel):
     def __init__(self, parent, master=None):
           
           self.parent = parent
           Toplevel.__init__(self, master)


class Window():
      def __init__(self,master): #constructor   
           self.master = master       
           self.master.title("Borras Roofing Quotation System") #sets title of window

           self.master.geometry("400x440") #sets size of window  
           self.master.configure(background = "white") # sets background colour of window.

           self.Borras = PhotoImage(file = "Borras.Logo.PNG") #sets up image
           self.BorrasLabel  = Label(self.master, image = self.Borras, bg = "white") #puts image onto label  
           self.BorrasLabel.place(x = 10, y = 50)  

           self.newquote = PhotoImage(file = "Process_New_Quote_Button.PNG") #sets up image  
           self.newquoteLabel = Label(self.master, image = self.newquote, bg = "white") #puts image onto label  
           self.newquoteLabel.place(x = 150, y = 50) 

           self.searchquote = PhotoImage(file = "Search_Current_Quote_Button.PNG") #sets up image  
           self.searchquoteLabel = Label(self.master, image = self.searchquote, bg = "white") #puts image onto label  
           self.searchquoteLabel.place(x = 300, y = 50)
           search_quote = Button(text="Search quote", command=self.search)
           quote = Button(text="Quote", command=self.quote)
           search_quote.pack()
           quote.pack()

      def search(self):
           #Pass parent reference 'self'
           search(self)

      def quote(self):
           quote(self)     

root = Tk() 
userPassWindow = Window(root)  
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start you need to use instances of Button, not Label if you want to achieve anything by clicking on it. If you add

```
command = anyfunction
```

as an argument to a button then the function will be run when the button is pressed (the function can be declared either inside or outside the Class, depending on what scope you want). From there use the

```
.pack_forget()
```

or

```
.place_forget()
```

procedure to remove items (though this does NOT delete them) and pack, place or grid the new items in your "window". If you are looking for actual screens to pack and forget pack then you should use tkinter Frames. Here is a useful link that will show you how to use each widget correctly:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook